# how to count min, max and average from this query mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1dbde0d6227268a4eee4dee539a5d930

assume i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID INT,
  user_id INT,
  createdAt DATE,
  status_id INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 13, '2020-01-01', 8),
  (2, 13, '2020-01-03', 8),
  (3, 13, '2020-01-06', 8),
  (4, 13, '2020-01-02', 7),
  (5, 13, '2020-01-03', 7),
  (6, 14, '2020-03-03', 8),
  (7, 13, '2020-03-04', 4),
  (8, 15, '2020-04-04', 7),
  (9, 14, '2020-03-02', 6),
  (10, 14, '2020-03-10', 5),
  (11, 13, '2020-04-10', 8);
```

i want to count time different for every users in range date time that i need with this query

```
SELECT t1.user_id, 
       t1.createdAt cretecompare1, 
       t2.createdAt cretecompare2,
       DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff
-- table for a transaction
FROM test t1
-- table for prev. transaction
JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
            AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
            AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
      FROM test t3
      WHERE t3.status_id != 7
      GROUP BY t3.user_id
      HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
         AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t5
                   WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
                     AND t5.status_id != 7
                     AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
                     AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt) 
HAViNG cretecompare2  BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01';
```

after that, the results was like this

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+
|  user_id | cretecompare1 | cretecompare2 | diff |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+
|       14 | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-03    |    1 |
|       13 | 2020-01-06    | 2020-03-04    |   58 |
|       14 | 2020-03-03    | 2020-03-10    |    7 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+
```

i want to count the max diff, min diff and the average for diff with this query

```
SELECT t1.user_id, 
       t1.createdAt cretecompare1, 
       t2.createdAt cretecompare2,
       DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff,
       MIN(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) min_diff, 
       MAX(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) max_diff, 
       AVG(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) avg_diff
-- table for a transaction
FROM test t1
-- table for prev. transaction
JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
            AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
            AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
      FROM test t3
      WHERE t3.status_id != 7
      GROUP BY t3.user_id
      HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
         AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t5
                   WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
                     AND t5.status_id != 7
                     AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
                     AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt) 
HAViNG cretecompare2  BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01'
```

and its says

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db_2015623402.t1.user_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

expected results

```
+-----+-----+---------+
| MIN | MAX | AVERAGE |
+-----+-----+---------+
|   1 |  58 |      22 |
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick. You are looking for a summary of data within the data you have so you can wrap it in `SELECT ()`, give the whole thing an alias at the end (`t`) and use the functions like `min()`, `max()`, and `avg()` like normal.

```
SELECT min(diff) as min, max(diff) as max, format(avg(diff),0) as avg  FROM (SELECT t1.user_id, 
       t1.createdAt cretecompare1, 
       t2.createdAt cretecompare2,
       DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff
-- table for a transaction
FROM test t1
-- table for prev. transaction
JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
            AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
            AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
      FROM test t3
      WHERE t3.status_id != 7
      GROUP BY t3.user_id
      HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
         AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t5
                   WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
                     AND t5.status_id != 7
                     AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
                     AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt) 
HAViNG cretecompare2  BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01') t
```